# something about css text-align:center

Tags: html, css, text-align

I have write a page like the page below ,just copy the same css style code , but text-align happens something.
http://mp.weixin.qq.com/s?__biz=MjM5ODQwMjA4MA==&mid=2649293603&idx=1&sn=57f38200555dcba76d6358594416c089&scene=1&srcid=0922hwo0hW1YFpZ5km00qu8f#rd

the text with red line should be center .and where does align:left come from? I haven't write this in code. It's source code of html file I write.

[image]

style code of text here is :

```css
<section style="box-sizing: border-box; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><section style=" box-sizing: border-box; "><section style=" margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; "><section style="box-sizing: border-box; text-align: center;"><section style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;padding: 8px 5px 5px 3px;width: 50%;box-sizing: border-box;border-right: 1px solid #66CCC5;"><section style="box-sizing: border-box;"><section  style="margin-top: 0.5em; margin-bottom: 0.5em; box-sizing: border-box;"><section style="box-sizing: border-box;width: 4em;height: 4em;display: inline-block;vertical-align: bottom;border-radius: 100%;background-image: url(&quot;http://mmbiz.qpic.cn/mmbiz/xpE6LLZTjLjZbC3icL0gxysDXhDQB9iaUPkFkZTfWxshdqfjuibeO84QQRovVcvYY4yhRLQPHusytjcicic7iav0GNvg/0?wx_fmt=jpeg&quot;);background-size: cover;background-position: 50% 50%;background-repeat: no-repeat;" class=""><br></section><p><span style="font-size: 14px;color: rgb(102, 204, 197);line-height: 1.6;">阿禅 Jason Ng</span></p></section></section></section><section style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;padding: 6px;width: 50%;box-sizing: border-box;"><section style="box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid rgb(102, 204, 197); padding: 8px 5px; width: 120px; color: rgb(102, 204, 197); border-radius: 2px; margin: auto; line-height: 20px; font-size: 14px;"><p>读完本文<br>大约需要</p><section style="font-size: 30px;color:#666;line-height: 38px;">6</section>分钟</section></section></section></section></section></section><
```

source code: view-source:http://7rf31y.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/index.html
you could copy and paste a local html file, then open it with chrome.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Paulie_D added some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

span has no align style defaults, but p does, so span inherits p style including left alignment. 
First of all i dont see any reason to put this span into a p, you can simply use the P, but it's not relevant...
You must add a class on the container and container > paragraf to center text as follows:

```css
.foo, .foo > p{text-align:center;}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <p class="foo2">
    <span>
      lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

It must work without using child declaration but as i dont know your stylement i let you as is to prevent errors. And please, don't style in html tags -.-

Cheers!